# How to vectorize comparisons instead of for-loop in R?

Tags: r, performance, for-loop, simulation, vectorization

I would like to run a discrete-time simulation (simplified version below).  I generate a data frame of population members (one member per row) with their timestamps for entering and exiting a website.  I then wish to count at each time interval how many members are on the site.

Currently I am looping through time and at each second counting how many members have entered and not yet exited.  (I have also tried destructive iteration by removing exited members at each interval, which takes even longer.  I also understand that I can use larger time intervals in the loop.)

How do I use linear algebra to eliminate the for-loop and excess runtime?  My current approach does not scale well as population increases, and of course it is linear with respect to duration.

```
popSize = 10000
simDuration = 10000
enterTimestamp <- rexp(n = popSize, rate = .001)
exitTimestamp <- enterTimestamp + rexp(n = popSize, rate = .001)
popEvents <- data.frame(cbind(enterTimestamp,exitTimestamp))
visitorLoad <- integer(length = simDuration)
for (i in 1:simDuration) {
  visitorLoad[i] <- sum(popEvents$enterTimestamp <= i & 
                        popEvents$exitTimestamp > i)  
  if (i %% 100 == 0) {print(paste('Sim at',i,'out of',simDuration,
                      'seconds.',sep=' ') )}
}
plot(visitorLoad, typ = 'l', ylab = 'Visitor Load', xlab='Time Elapsed (sec)')
```

Comment: Check ?subset and ?ifelse functions.

Comment: I don't see a way to use linear algebra for this, nor a way to get out of the O(N) runtime (other than adapting the time interval based on the length of the simulation).  However, the *Rcpp* package may be of help with the wallclock time of the routine.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg I think the issue was that there was really a O(N^2) runtime in the for-loop approach (you need to consider every combination of time interval and visitor). My solution below (and Troy's edited solution, which is essentially the same approach) improve this to O(N) runtime.

Comment: @josilber Good point.  The vector operations within the `for` loop are themselves O(N).  Of course this means that your solution will scale much better.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can obtain the counts of visitors entering and exiting at different times and then use the cumulative sum to compute the number of visitors there at a particular time. This seems to meet your requirement of the code running quickly, though it does not use linear algebra.

```
diffs = rep(0, simDuration+1)

# Store the number of times a visitor enters and exits at each timestep. The table
# will contain headers that are the timesteps and values that are the number of
# people entering or exiting at the timestep.
tabEnter = table(pmax(1, ceiling(enterTimestamp)))
tabExit = table(pmin(simDuration+1, ceiling(exitTimestamp)))

# For each time index, add the number of people entering and subtract the number of
# people exiting. For instance, if in period 20, 3 people entered and 4 exited, then
# diffs[20] equals -1. as.numeric(names(tabEnter)) is the periods for which at least
# one person entered, and tabEnter is the number of people in each of those periods.
diffs[as.numeric(names(tabEnter))] = diffs[as.numeric(names(tabEnter))] + tabEnter
diffs[as.numeric(names(tabExit))] = diffs[as.numeric(names(tabExit))] - tabExit

# cumsum() sums the diffs vector through a particular time point. 
visitorLoad2 = head(cumsum(diffs), simDuration)
```

Comment: It's worth noting that this is 100 times faster than the `for` loop.

Comment: I would suggest editing this answer to explain what each step is doing, and why it gives the results it does.  It is an inventive solution but it is not easily understood.  Also note that the final value is incorrectly reported here as 0, and should be 3 (probably a very easy fix, but I don't see what the issue is right off).

Comment: @MatthewLundberg added comments and adjusted the final value.

Comment: Very nice.  I would suggest `head(cumsum(diffs), simDuration)` but that's just style.

Comment: Thank you very much for this creative solution.  Troy's solution below was closer to what I was expecting -- it did not occur to me to separately tabulate entries and exits and then calculate the population in the system as the cumulative sum of entries minus exits.

Answer (score 1):

How about this for simplicity:

```
vl<-unlist(lapply(1:simDuration,function(i)sum((enterTimestamp<=i)*(exitTimestamp>i))))
plot(vl, typ = 'l', ylab = 'Visitor Load', xlab='Time Elapsed (sec)')
```

It's twice as fast as current loop, but if performance is more important then @josilber 's solution is better, or maybe something with `data.table()`, will have a think...

**EDIT** - how about this for speed:

```
require(data.table)
require(plyr) # for count() function

system.time({

enter<-data.table(count(ceiling(enterTimestamp))) # entries grouped by second
exit<-data.table(count(ceiling(exitTimestamp)))   # exits grouped by second
sim<-data.table(x=1:simDuration)                  # time index
merged<-merge(merge(sim,enter,by="x",all.x=T),exit,by="x",all.x=T)
mat<-data.matrix(merged[,list(freq.x,freq.y)])    # make matrix to remove NAs
mat[is.na(mat)]<-0                                # remove NAs, there are quicker ways but more complicated
vl<-cumsum(mat[,1]-mat[,2])                       # cumsum() to roll up the movements

})

user  system elapsed 
0.02    0.00    0.02 

plot(vl, typ = 'l', ylab = 'Visitor Load', xlab='Time Elapsed (sec)')
```

** FURTHER EDIT ** - balance of performance and simplicity

```
system.time(cumsum(data.frame(table(cut(enterTimestamp,0:10000))-table(cut(exitTimestamp,0:10000)))[,2]))
user  system elapsed 
0.09    0.00    0.10
```

Comment: This certainly is an improvement.  Also, one can use sapply() instead of unlist(lapply()), correct?  And thank you for system.time; I had not seen that before.  I would +1 if I could.

Comment: The `lapply` solution is faster than the `for` loop only because the `print` statements have been removed.

Comment: @MatthewLundberg no it's 2x without the print statement, 3x with (on my laptop anyway). The data.table solution's 200x faster but not as intuitive, maybe.